# Help me with "come into" collocations

Tags: phrasal-verbs, collocations

I've just learned that the meaning of "come into" is : be important or relevant.

However I don't get the following sentence:

> to come into a person's possession without having been paid for.

Does someone would show me the most commons collocations and respective meanings of "come into" in some sentences?

I've found some examples which I got the meaning:

> [come into something] to be an aspect of a situation

- The argument was over artistic freedom – money never **came into** it.

  ---

> [come into something] if you come into something, it becomes yours when someone dies

- He’s just **come into** some money

  ---

> come into your own to show how effective or useful you can be

- In the wintry conditions the Norwegian team really **came into** their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all idiomatic expressions that centre around a more basic definition of "come in" which means to enter, or join something.

*To come into a person's possession* means that something which once did not belong to the person has now become their possession. It is like the item has *joined* a group, the person's existing possessions.

*To come into [a situation]* means to enter a situation that already existed - for example, if you started working for a company and they were already in financial difficulty when you became employed by them, you might say that was a situation you had *come into*.

*Come into money* means that you suddenly went from having little or no money, to having a considerable amount. It often refers to *inheritances*, so again, the money already existed and you *came into it*.

*Come into your own* means to find that you are successful at something, particularly if you have suddenly found a hidden talent - so the talent was already there, dormant in you, and now you have found it.

These idioms are really unrelated and not used in exactly the same sentence structures - the only thing they really have in common is different idiomatic uses of the phrasal verb "to come in".

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you very much.